# Make ImageView disappear after setting it

Tags: android, imageview

I cannot get rid of the ImageView after setting it (img.setImageResource(R.drawable.xxx);)! 
I tried everything:

```
img.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)
```

and

```
img.setVisibility(View.GONE)
```

and

```
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.width=0;
params.height=0;
```

Also searched a lot about this.
Can anyone help?

Comment: You will need to post some more code.  From what You have posted its hard to tell what might be going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This *should* work, as long as you execute it in a GUI thread (not in a Thread, not in background AsyncTask) and you NOT do something like "make invisible; do longrunning calculations; make visible again" in one single piece of code.

Comment: That did it! Got the setvisibility out of the thread!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why that isn't working, but as an extreme solution you can try removing the View entirely. Call removeView( img ); on the ViewGroup (the layout) that directly contains the ImageView.